# how to add users to firestore using the same id after authentication

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication

```
const handleSignup = ()=>{
    auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((cred) => {
        console.log(cred);
        firestore()
        .collection('users')
        .doc(cred.uid)
        .set({
          display_name:username
        })
        .then(() => {
          console.log('User added!');
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.code);
        if (error.code === 'auth/user-not-found') {
          console.error('Invalid Email or password');
        }else
          console.error('Sorry an error occured');
    });
  };
```

I am using the above code to store user details in firestore and I want the document to be same as the credentials uid which is generated after authnetication.But the id in the doc is completely different that the cred.uid.How to fix this?

Comment: what does the `cred` console.log display? I'm not 100% sure, but isn't the uid stored inside `cred.user.uid`? (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth seems to suggest the same thing: to use `cred.user`)

Comment: Yaa my bad! It's working now. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like an answer @Berci  :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is `cred.user.uid` (instead of `cred.uid`). For source and more information about this topic check [firebase password auth docs](http://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth).

PS: This was already answered in the comments but I posted the response here as well to be easier to spot (as well as suggest that the question has an answer. Thank you *@Frank van Puffelen* for the suggestion).